# Proof If $A^2=A$, then $A=I$ or $A$ isn't invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Here is what I have done so far:

$A^2=A \Rightarrow A=A\cdot A^{-1}\Rightarrow A=I$.

I am unsure how to formally prove that if this is not the case, $A$ must be invertible. I see that if there are cases in which a column or row of zeros in the matrix causes $A^2=A$ but don't know how to prove this formally.

Comment: If $A$ isn't invertible, then you're done. If $A$ is invertible then do what you did

Comment: @ZacharySelk How do I show that $A$ being invertible is the only other case that is possible?

Comment: Taking determinants you get $\det A = 0,1$, so either $A$ is invertible with $\det A = 1$ or not invertible. You proved that if $A$ is invertible then $A = I$.

Comment: A matrix is defined to be "*not invertible*" if and only if it is not *invertible*.  By the very nature of the definition of "*not invertible*" there are only two cases possible, invertible or not.

Comment: Either $A$ is invertible or its not. If it's not, we're done. If it is, then do what you did.

Comment: @JMoravitz I am going to delete my answer because your comment here and that by ZacharySelk provide a correct and sufficient answer.

Answer (score 3):

$A^2=A$ implies that $A(A-I)=0$, we deduce that $Im(A-I)\subset Ker(A)$. If $Im(A-I)\neq \{0\}$, then $A$ is not invertible since its kernel is not zero. If $Im(A-I)=0$, then $A=I$.

Answer (score 0):

$A(A-I)=0$ implies that all the eigenvalues of $A$ belong to $\{0,1\}$. By considering the Jordan normal form of $A$, if an eigenvalue had a geometric multiplicity $>1$ the equality $A=A^2$ would be impossible, so $A$ is diagonalizable and 
$$ A = J^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 & \ldots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \ldots & \lambda_n\end{pmatrix} J=J^{-1}D J,\qquad J\in\text{GL}_n,\;\lambda_k\in\{0,1\}.$$
If some $\lambda_k$ is zero $A$ is not invertible. If all the eigenvalues equal one, $A=J^{-1} I J = J^{-1} J = I$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A^2=A$ or $A(A-I)=0$. Either $A=I$ or there is some non-zero element $x$ of the range of $A-I$ for which $Ax=0$, which forces $A$ to be non-invertible.