# How to prove the statement "If A^2 = A and A ≠ I<sub>n</sub> , then det(A) = 0" if it is true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Statement: If A<sup>2</sup> = A and A ≠ I<sub>n</sub> , then det(A) = 0

We know that A is not invertible if its kernel is not zero. We also note that  A<sup>2</sup>=A  implies that A(A−I)=0

Now, how can I apply the same logic within this statement to prove if it is either true or false?

similar question(also based to make the question):
[Proof If $A^2=A$, then $A=I$ or $A$ isn't invertible.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2563501/proof-if-a2-a-then-a-i-or-a-isnt-invertible)

Comment: The duplicate is exactly the same as your question. If $A\neq I$, then $A$ is singular, so that $\det(A)=0$.

Comment: Oh I see, thus the statement above is then true?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, the question link is my basis and you just sent it again, that's why I'm trying to clarify if my question above also resonates the question link and if both of them contain the same logic.

Comment: Since that is the case, then my statement above is true? @DietrichBurde

Comment: Your statement  is the same as the other statement. So both are equally true. The duplicate gives two nice proofs.

Comment: Ok, got it, that would do to resolve my clarification. Thank you very much for you response @DietrichBurde

Comment: Yes. The two consequences $A=I$ and $\det(A)=0$ are mutually different, since $\det(I)=1\neq 0$. So it is the same as saying "either $A=I$ or $\det(A)=0$."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138825/discussion-between-ralph-henry-and-dietrich-burde).